# Handling Yahoo Finance Quotes Hash in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yahoo

I am trying to manipulate the hash returned from Yahoo Finance for their Standard Quote using Ruby on Rails. I am new to Ruby and am getting a compile error in a view .erb file when I try to run the program. My objective is relatively straightforward - I want to display the Stock symbol, Bid and Ask prices and Corp name for each quote contained in the hash.

I stored the hash in an instance variable called @quote_info and pass this hash to the View.

The code in the view is as folows :

```
 <h1>Stock Quote from Yahoo Finance</h1>

   <p>Stock Symbol(s) Requested: <%= @quote_list %> </p>



   <table>
     <tr>
    <th>Symbol</th>
    <th>Bid Price</th>
    <th>Ask Price</th>
  </tr>

  <% @quote_info.each |stock| do %>
    <tr>
    <td><%= stock.symbol %></td>
    <td><%= stock.bid %></td>
    <td><%= stock.ask %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
   </table>
```

I get a compile error on the each statement line , pointing to after the do term.

```
compile error
/home/lvl9/waf_projects/squotes_app/app/views/screenquotes/show.html.erb:18: syntax error, unexpected kDO
');@output_buffer.append_if_string=    @quote_info.each |stock| do 
                                                              ^
```

Any thoughts would be much appreciated. I am tearing my hair out and cannot afford to lose any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a misplaced `do`:

```
<% @quote_info.each do |stock| %>
```

Comment: Now its rejecting the stock.symbol term - seesymbol as undefined method.Hash structure below :

Comment: @JoeMcGouran Can't help with that unless you include more info; I don't know what is supposed to be there.

Comment: See compile details below:NoMethodError in Screenquotes#show

Showing /home/lvl9/waf_projects/squotes_app/app/views/screenquotes/show.html.erb where line #24 raised:

undefined method `symbol' for "ibm":String

Extracted source (around line #24):

21: 
22: <% @quote_list.each do |stock| %>
23:   <tr>
24:     <td><%= stock.symbol %></td>
25:     <td><%= stock.name %></td>
26:     <td><%= stock.bid.to_s %></td>
27:     <td><%= stock.ask.to_s %></td>

Rails.root: /home/lvl9/waf_projects/squotes_app  -

Comment: @JoeMcGouran I can't read that. Edit the original question, or better yet, ask a new one since it's completely unrelated to the original one. The issue is the data, not the code, except maybe for the part that gets the data.